# How to update multiple actor's position at the same time in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

im currently trying to update a multiple actor's position in libgdx.
at first i did it on render event but it made fps slow.
Now im updating the libgdx on a different thread but render is getting called halfway while im updating the possitions. is there a way where i can update all of the possitions and render it when they are all ready?

Comment: How many actors you've ?

Comment: i got around 120 actors. im running it on android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the actors have different positions we can use `addAction(Actions.moveTo(x,y))`.

However, if they are relative to one another, it's better to group them using scene2d ui group class and then update that group's position using `addAction(Actions.moveTo(x,y))`.